# Pgfplots circles

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having a little trouble drawing circles in pgfplots.  Here is my code and then I'll explain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(0,0)}]
\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$}]
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {3*x+2};
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {2*x+2};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(1,3)};
\draw(axis cs:0,3) circle[blue, radius=1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Imagine infintely many concentric circles about (0,3).  The actual numbers and line equations aren't important; I'm only interested in showing the following relationship: as the line gets steeper, it is tangent to a circle of smaller radius at a higher \pi and lower x.

I know there is probably a way for LaTeX to take care of the tangencies for me through intersections or something, but I'm fine with doing the math on my own.  My main problem is how can I code the radius of the circle in terms of the coordinates?  For example, in my code, the circle has radius one, so it should intersect with the far right red dot.  But it doesn't, it's so small you can't see it.

Please let me know if you don't understand my request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since version 1.5.1 of PGFPlots, circle and ellipse radii are interpreted in terms of axis units (which is what you want). However, to maintain backwards compatibility, this feature isn't activated by default: you'll have to set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}` (or higher).

If you do that, you'll notice that you get an ellipse instead of a circle. That's because your axes aren't scaled equally. Setting `axis equal` (or `axis equal image`) will get you a proper circle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$},
    axis equal image
]
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {3*x+2};
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {2*x+2};
\addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates {(0,3) (1,3)};
\draw (axis cs:0,3) circle [blue, radius=1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's how you can draw the tangent line and point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\d{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{acos(\r/\d)}

\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0, ymax=6,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$},
    axis equal image,clip mode=individual
]
\draw (axis cs:0,\d) circle [radius=\r];
\node [
    fill,
    red,
    circle,
    inner sep=1.5pt
] (tangent)  at (axis cs:{\r*sin(\angle)},{\d-\r*cos(\angle)}) {};
\draw [shorten >=-1cm] (axis cs:0,0) -- (tangent);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this code but got the following error:

Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.5.1' unknown in key 
'/pgfplots/compat/labels'. I am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
                              
?

Comment: I decide to update my Tex distribution to see if that would help.  Well, now I'm getting a different error: "Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1.0*s
in(70.54903)' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '
*sin(70.54903)'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                    "

Comment: @user21359: What versions of PGFPlots and TikZ are  you using now (check your `.log` file)?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to determine the radius in terms of the coordinates. Here is how.

1. Assign a name to the points of interests. See `\path (axis cs:x,y) coordinate (name);`
2. Assign them to commands `\p1`, `\p2` and use `veclen` to determine the length of radius.  `calc` from tikzlibrary is required

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(0,0)}]
\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    %axis equal=true,  % The plot was obtained with this marked out, since your code does not have this.
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$}]
\path (axis cs:0,3) coordinate (A);       %%%%
\path (axis cs:1,3) coordinate (B);       %%%%
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {3*x+2};
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {2*x+2};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};  
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(1,3)};  
\draw[blue] let \p1=(A),\p2=(B), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in (A) circle[radius=\n1];                           %%%%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```